# Inverse Transform Predicted Results

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, inverse-transform

I have a training data CSV with three columns (two for data and a third for targets) and I successfully predicted the target column for my test CSV. The problem is I need to inverse transform the results back to strings for further analysis. Below is the code and error.

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import defaultdict

df_train = pd.read_csv('/Users/justinchristensen/Documents/Python_Education/SKLearn/Path_Training_Data.csv')
df_test = pd.read_csv('/Users/justinchristensen/Documents/Python_Education/SKLearn/Path_Test_Data.csv')

#Separate columns in training data set
x_train = df_train.iloc[:,:-1]
y_train = df_train.iloc[:,-1:]

#Separate columns in test data set
x_test = df_test.iloc[:,:-1]

#Initiate classifier
clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100)
le = LabelEncoder()

#Transform strings into integers
x_train_encoded = x_train.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
y_train_encoded = y_train.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
x_test_encoded = x_test.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)

#Fit the model into the classifier
clf.fit(x_train_encoded,y_train_encoded)

#Predict test values
y_pred = clf.predict(x_test_encoded)
```

The error

```
NotFittedError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-09840b0071d5> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 y_pred_inverse = le.inverse_transform(y_pred)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py in inverse_transform(self, y)
    146         y : numpy array of shape [n_samples]
    147         """
--> 148         check_is_fitted(self, 'classes_')
    149 
    150         diff = np.setdiff1d(y, np.arange(len(self.classes_)))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_is_fitted(estimator, attributes, msg, all_or_any)
    766 
    767     if not all_or_any([hasattr(estimator, attr) for attr in attributes]):
--> 768         raise NotFittedError(msg % {'name': type(estimator).__name__})
    769 
    770 

NotFittedError: This LabelEncoder instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the same label object which you used for transforming your targets to get them back. Each time you use the Label Enocder you instantiated a new object. Use the same object.

Change the following line

```
y_train_encoded = y_train.apply(le().fit_transform)
y_test_encoded = y_test.apply(le().fit_transform)
```

Then use the same object to reverse the transformation. You can check the [first example here in the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) for reference as well.